# No kernel of the form $\lvert x - y\rvert^{-1}$ on tempered distributions?

Tags: pr.probability, schwartz-distributions, integral-operators

Does there exist a continuous bilinear form $\mathcal{B}$ on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})\times \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ such that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{B}(\varphi_1, \varphi_2) =\int_{\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}} \frac{\varphi_1(x) \varphi_2(y)}{\lvert x - y \rvert} \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
\end{equation}
for every $\varphi_1, \varphi_2 \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ with disjoint supports?

*Context:* 
A bilinear form $\mathcal{B}$ comes together with a kernel $K \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R})$ such that $\mathcal{B}(\varphi_1 ,\varphi_2) = \langle K , \varphi_1 \otimes \varphi_2 \rangle$ (by the kernel theorem). The restriction to functions with disjoint supports allows us to avoid possible diagonal problems for the kernel $K$. It is possible to define a valid kernel of the form $K(x,y) = \lvert x - y \rvert^{-\lambda}$ outside the diagonal for $0<\lambda<1$.
My guess is here that this is impossible for $\lambda = 1$, and therefore that it is impossible to find a bilinear form $\mathcal{B}$ satisfying the equation above when restricted to test functions with disjoint supports. Is this correct and if yes, how can one prove it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Let $K\in S'(\mathbb{R}^2)$ be the distribution acting on test functions $f(x,y)$ by
$$
K(f)=\int_{|x-y|\ge 1} \frac{f(x,y)}{|x-y|}\ dx\ dy
\ + \int_{|x-y|< 1} \frac{f(x,y)-f(x,x)}{|x-y|}\ dx\ dy\ .
$$
What is impossible is to do this extension to the diagonal while preserving the degree -1 homogeneity. The only homogeneous distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ with this homogeneity is delta at the origin (up to scale).

A good reference for this type of questions is vol 1 of "Generalized Functions"
by Gelfand and Shilov. This becomes interesting in the context of probability theory see:
[Squaring random Schwartz distributions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201997/squaring-random-schwartz-distributions)

A related question is: can one interpret the energy field for the 2d Ising critical scaling limit as a random distribution?

Also a considerable amplification of this kind of methods for extending distributions to the diagonal is BPHZ renormalization. See, e.g., this lecture by Hairer: http://www.mathtube.org/lecture/video/bphz-theorem-stochastic-pdes-0

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your insightful answer. Could you clarify for me why the second integral in the formula for $K(f)$ is finite?

Comment: Or, could you perhaps help me with [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466638/for-a-tempered-distribution-f-on-mathbbr2-what-exactly-does-it-mean-by)? I can feel some sort of connection between this link and your answer.

Comment: It's quite trivial and follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus $f(x,y)-f(x,x)=(y-x)\int_0^1 dt\ \partial_2 f(x,x+t(y-x))$, where $\partial_2$ means partial derivative with respect to the second argument.

Answer (score 5):

(Edit: see below... I misread the question...) One particular way to regularize that integral, relating to meaningful things, is by viewing it as Hilbert transform applied to one Schwartz function, producing (at worst) a tempered distribution, which is then applied to the second Schwartz function.

Part of the point is that the Hilbert transform, or already the principal value integral attached to $1/x$ in one variable, is *not* a literal integral (against a locally $L^1$ function), although it is a perfectly fine tempered distribution (the derivative of the locally integrable $\log|x|$).

Another implicit aspect, mentioned by @Abdelmalek Abdesselam, is to think about such an *extension* problem, by (uniquely?!?) *characterizing* the restricted operator by symmetry/homogeneity, etc., and explicitly ask whether there *exists* an extension that preserves those features, and whether the extension is *unique*. (This can be usefully written as a homological issue, as I first saw in a paper of Casselman about extended notions of automorphic forms.) For example, the p.v. integral against $1/x$, rather than $1/x$ itself, is the unique distribution (up to multiples) with that homogeneity and parity, by the classification of distributions on $\mathbb R$ supported at $\{0\}$ and what amounts to an application of the snake lemma. (As usual, what can be usefully written as homological algebra, e.g., a snake lemma application, can also be done directly, in effect reproving a special case of the short-to-long business.)

EDIT: ooops, (thanks to Jean Duchon for noticing my error!): I dropped the absolute value in the question. Thus, this is *not* the Hilbert transform. In fact, in that vein, the symmetry and mildly homological extension argument *proves* that there is *no* distribution extending integration against $1/|x|$ (note the absolute values now), preserving the homogeneity and parity. (The positive-homogeneity is the same as $1/x$, but the parity is opposite. The existence of $\delta$, with the same positive-homogeneity and parity is equivalent to the non-extendability, in effect. The same arguments apply to Hadamard's finie-partie functionals, too.)

Comment: I think you forgot the |.|, your construction gives $\int\int\varphi_1(x)\varphi_2(y)/(x-y)\ dx\ dy$

Comment: @JeanDuchon, oops! you're correct! So, the argument I sketched then proves the _impossibility_...  Thanks for your observation! I will add a correction...

Answer (score 2):

You can try $\mathcal B(\varphi_1,\varphi_2)=\int \int\varphi'_1(x)\ \varphi_2'(y) (|x-y|\ln|x-y|)\ dx\ dy$ , i.e. $K$ is the second derivative $\partial_x\partial_y$ of (the distribution defined by) the locally integrable function $H(x,y)=|x-y|\ln|x-y|$ .

This extension is clearly non unique (since any distribution applied to $\varphi_1\varphi_2$ vanishes if the two functions have disjoint supports) but a somewhat standard solution (different from the one above) would use Schwartz's *pseudo-function* Pf. $r^m$ defined e.g. in *Théorie des distributions*, formula (II,3;4), a well-defined distribution whose restriction to $\{0\}^c$ coincides with the locally summable function $|x|^m$. This leads (via the Fourier transform of Pf. $r^{-1}$, formula (VII,7;18)) to $$\mathcal B(\varphi_1,\varphi_2)=-2[\int \hat{\varphi_1}(\xi)\ \hat{\varphi_2}(-\xi)\ln|\xi|\ d\xi\ +\ (\mathcal C+\ln(2\pi))\int\varphi_1\int\varphi_2]$$where $\mathcal C$ is Euler's constant. Or equivalently (through the definition of Pf. $r^{-1}$)$$\mathcal B(\varphi_1,\varphi_2)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}[\int\int_{|x-y|>\varepsilon}\frac{\varphi_1(x)\varphi_2(y)}{|x-y|}\ dx\ dy\ -\ I(\varepsilon)]$$where $I(\varepsilon)\propto \ln\varepsilon$ , i.e. the *finite part* of the possibly diverging integral.