# For a tempered distribution $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, what exactly does it mean by $\lvert F(x,y) \rvert \leq \lvert x-y \rvert^{-n}$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions

Let $F$ be a tempered distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be a fixed natural number. I wonder what exactly it means by

> $\lvert F(x,y) \rvert \leq \lvert x-y \rvert^{-n}$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

I run into such notations when dealing with a sequence of tempered distributions and their integral representation.

By definition, $F$ is a continuous linear functional on the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. So, I guess the above bound should be expressed in terms of Schwartz functions.

Could anyone please clarify for me?

Add : A reference context is [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-47/issue-3/Necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-integral-representations-of-Wightman-functionals/cmp/1103899756.full), with p.211 Eqn (6) in particular.

Add 2 : For those who down-voted it, could you please tell me what you don't like about this problem, for the sake of being constructive?

Comment: It is implicit in the hypotheses of Thm.5.1 there, which contains Eq.(6), that the $\mathfrak{S}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ (or your $F(x,y)$) are just ordinary functions away from the diagonals, not arbitrary distributions. This is very tersely explained in the text just preceding the theorem, but (again implicitly) the authors assume that the reader is already familiar with what Wightman/Schwinger functions are. So your original interpretation, which led to the confusion, is not correct.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine What do you mean by ordinary functions? The text clearly says they are tempered distributions so that they are integrated against test functions....I believe that you totally misunderstood the text..

Comment: In fact  the whole paper is about distributions..

Comment: @IgorKhavkine  Look at this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_function

Comment: "$\mathfrak{S}_n$ is defined and real analytic at all points $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ with $x_i \ne x_j$ for all $i,j$."

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Of course as tempered distributions. For example, non-coinciding points are the properties of the test functions they act on.....

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Look at the link above. It describes all your issues... To be honest, why would I have been bothered to write this question if Schwinger functions are just "ordinary functions"?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine If you down-voted my question because you thought I was wrong, can you revoke it?

Comment: For the record, I did not vote on this question. The last and only productive thing that I can add is that your question can be fully resolved by a careful rereading of Thm.5.1 and the paragraph before it.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine So, you still insist that Schwinger functions are "ordinary functions" and not tempered distributions?

Comment: @Isaac, I know not the physics but tempered distributions can be given by functions on certain subsets. For instance the Cauchy kernel is $K=\text{pv}1/x$ which is equal to $1/x$ away from $x=0$. Which precisely means that for say any test function $f$ compactly supported inside any open set $U$ that does not contain 0, $(f,K) =  (f,1/x)$

Comment: For distributions $T$ and $T_1$ on $\Omega$ and open $U\subseteq\Omega$ one can define $|\,T\,|\le T_1$ on $U$ to mean that $|\,T\,\varphi\,|\le T_1\varphi$ hold for nonnegative test functions $\varphi$ with support included in $U$. One can define $T$ to be "real" by requiring that it maps real test functions to real numbers, and one can define "positivity" of $T$ on $U$ by requiring that $0\le T\,\varphi$ hold for any nonnegative test function $\varphi$ with support included in $U$. For real $T$ then $|\,T\,|\le T_1$ on $U$ reduces to $T_1$ and $T_1-T$ and $T_1+T$ being positive on $U$.

Comment: By the way, I think this kind of questions are not "research level" and should be asked on/migrated to MSE.

Comment: @TaQ Well, $\lvert x-y \rvert^{-n}$ is not necessarily a tempered distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$. What if $n$ is very big?

Comment: @TaQ If it is a distribution, what can be the "domain" for it? Could you provide any appropriate sub-class of Schwartz functions? I expect the domain to depend on the singular exponent $n$.

Comment: Anyway, on the open set $U$ given by $x\not=y$ it is a distribution, although not tempered. One should here take $\Omega=U$ and consider "$F(x,y)$" restricted on it, defined for test functions $\varphi$ in $\mathscr D(\Omega)$, independently of $n$. (I deleted my above comment to avoid putting too many.)

Comment: @TaQ Well, what would such a tset function $\phi$ look like? I don't think this whole thing is some trivial question at the level of textbook exercise.

Comment: @TaQ Plus, $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ is not a nuclear tame Frechet space, but some LF space. This already loses many advantages of the Schwartz space including [Nash-Moser theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash%E2%80%93Moser_theorem#Tame_Fr%C3%A9chet_space). I see that this sort of topic lies in your area of expertise.

Comment: "what would such a tset function $\phi$ look like" ... "$\mathcal D(\Omega)$ is not a nuclear tame Frechet space" ... I don't see the relevance of these to the OP, and MO suggests to avoid extended discussions. So this is my last comment here.

Comment: @TaQ OK, it is your choice. However my concern is about non-existence of such $\phi$, which invalidates your whole argument so far. So, I see direct relevance here, contrary to your view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try to explain what Igor meant in his comments in a different way, maybe it helps.

1. Of course, any tempered distribution is a distribution in the broader sense - more precisely, any compactly supported test function is tempered, and the seminorms defining the topology of $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are majorized by seminorms defining the topology of $\mathscr{C}^\infty(K)$ for all $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ compact with nonvoid interior.
2. Any distribution $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (tempered or not, by 1.) may be restricted to a nonvoid open subset $U$ thereof by restricting to test functions supported in $U$. The result is, of course, a distribution $u|_U$ in $U$ (which is no longer tempered because temperedness only has meaning if $U=\mathbb{R}^n$), for the needed seminorm bounds guaranteeing the continuity of $u|_U$ are clearly inherited from those of $u$.
3. A basic theorem in distribution theory tells us that if two continuous functions $f,g$ on $U$ as in 2. are such that $$ \int_U f\phi\,dx=\int_U g\phi\,dx$$ for all test functions $\phi$ compactly supported in $U$, then $f=g$. This means that if $f$ is a continuous function on $U$ such that $$u|_U(\phi)=u(\phi)=\int_U f\phi\,dx$$ for all such test functions, then $f$ is the *only* continuous function on $U$ with such a property, and therefore we may *identify* $u|_U$ with (the smearing of compactly supported test functions on $U$ with) $f$. More generally, this can be done with $f$ any locally integrable function on $U$, but then the identification is only up to a zero-measure subset of $U$ because of the integral in the rhs. This freedom disappears if $f$ is required to be continuous. In the case of $n$-point Schwinger functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$, $$U=\mathbb{R}^{nd}\smallsetminus\{(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{nd}\ |\ x_i\in\mathbb{R}^d\ ,i=1,\ldots,n\ ,\,x_j=x_k\text{ for some }j\neq k\}$$ and $f$ is a real analytic (hence continuous) function, so $f$ is the *unique* such function.

1.-3. together explain what your inequality means - to wit, it *implicitly* states that the restriction $F|_U$ of $F$ to the open subset $U=\mathbb{R}^2\smallsetminus\{(x,x)\ |\ x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is identified with (the smearing of compactly supported test functions on $U$ with) a(n at least locally integrable) function $f$ on $U$ which then satisfies the given inequality, since the latter's rhs is clearly only defined in $U$. In the context of the paper, $f$ is real analytic and therefore continuous as in the end of 3., so $f$ is *unique* and thus the given inequality has a clear, unambiguous meaning.

Hope it helped somehow to understand Igor's comments. Sorry if my answer sounds pedantic at places, but I wanted to be sure not to leave any stone unturned.

Comment: In due time: as Abdelmalek said at the end of its answer, strictly speaking it may not always be the case that if one *starts* with an analytic function $f$ on $U$ as in the end of 3. above, the boundary values of $f$ on the big diagonal exist in the tempered distribution sense. One needs polynomial bounds such as the one in the OP to ensure that, otherwise one generally only obtains that way what is called a "hyperfunction", which is even more singular than a distribution.

Comment: The first paper by Osterwalder and Schrader on the reconstruction of the Wightman $n$-point functions from the corresponding Schwinger $n$-point functions overlooked that point, and a proper discussion of this matter in the context of hyperfunction theory was provided in their second paper (as well as in an independent paper by Glaser).

Comment: I should also qualify my 1st comment: "boundary values of $f$" are really meant in the sense of holomorphic functions viewed as distributions. The imaginary part of their argument is seen as parameters sent to zero in the distribution sense while keeping the real part at the complement of $U$ - depending on the direction one approaches zero, one may get a different boundary value.

Comment: Generally there are many ways to continuously extend a distribution $u$ from $\mathscr{D}(U)$ to $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, taking boundary values of $u$ identified with a real analytic function $f$ on $U$, which then admits a unique extension to a holomorphic function on an open domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$ containing $U$, is a particular case. These extensions are collectively called *renormalizations*, and their existence is ensured by the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much. After some thoughts, I don't think Theorem 5.1 in [the above paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-47/issue-3/Necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-integral-representations-of-Wightman-functionals/cmp/1103899756.full) is not really correct. We just need the extra condition $(E0'')$ stated in p.287 of the second paper of Osterwalder and Schrader.

Comment: According to the proof of Theorem 5.1 in [the above paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-47/issue-3/Necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-integral-representations-of-Wightman-functionals/cmp/1103899756.full) , we only need $\hat{\tau}$-continuity of the given sequence of Schwinger functions. That is exactly the extra condition $(E0)''$ in the second paper of Osterwalder-Schrader.

Comment: I can't understand at all why the authors of [the above paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-47/issue-3/Necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-integral-representations-of-Wightman-functionals/cmp/1103899756.full) imposed this UV growth bound instead, which does not seem to relate directly to required $\hat{\tau}$-continuity. Perhaps, could you provide any insight?

Comment: I can see your profile link. If you do not mind, is it okay for me to discuss my issue more in detail with you by email?

Comment: @Isaac we may continue this discussion by email, no problem, also because we're kind of departing from the strict matter of the OP.

Comment: I sent you an email summarizing my issues! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Distributions and ordinary functions are two different things, however, there are bridges between them, going both ways, modulo some technical hypotheses. If $f$ is an ordinary function one can associate to it a distribution that sends a smooth test function g to $\int fg$, i.e., by "integrating against $f$" as mentioned in the article. For this to make sense, i.e., for the integral to converge and the resulting linear form to be continuous, the needed technical hypothesis is that $f$ is locally $L^1$. Conversely, given a distribution $T$ on $\Omega$, it has a singular support $K$, which allows one to produce a smooth function $f$ by "restriction" to $\Omega\backslash K$. Namely, that means that if $g$ is a test function with support in $\Omega\backslash K$, then $T(g)=\int_{\Omega\backslash K} fg$.

Traditionally, Schwinger functions are defined as ordinary functions with domain given by the complement of the big diagonal, i.e., for non-coinciding points. Then, one can ask if one can associate a distribution to that. This is a bit tricky because this does not use the standard spaces of distributions say PDE folks work with.